# Replacing Text with replacetext() and defining said replacement as heading

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-docs

I have a Google spreadsheet and a Google document. The document is a report which gets filled by the spreadsheet. The spreadsheet is also defining what comes into the report. Therefore I have a script, which gathers a bunch of placeholders depending on values in the the document.

After all the placeholders have been inserted in the document (there are a couple of pages before that) it looks kind of like this:

```
{{header1.1}}
{{text1.1}}//this is already a couple lines of text
{{table1.1}}
{{table.dir}}
{{blob1.1}}
{{blob.dir}}
```

I already have a script, which inserts all the text parts and I have set up a script, which should be capable of writing the tables at the correct position. So far I can replace the {{header1.1}}, but if I try to define it as a heading it works, but everything after the header1.1 is also a heading

I've been at this problem for quite a while and didn't get and its always one step forward one step back. Also this is my first question after a couple of years just reading on stackoverflow. I'd appreciate if someone could help.

```
function myUeberschriftenboi() {
doc = DocumentApp.openById('someID');
console.log(doc.getName());
var body = doc.getBody();
//formate
const plain3style = {};
plain3style[DocumentApp.Attribute.HEADING] =  DocumentApp.ParagraphHeading.HEADING3;    
var lvl2array = [ "{{header1.1}}" , "{{header1.2}}" ];
var fill2array = [ "Energy" , "Energyflow" ] 
var lvl2count = 1;
for( var j = 0 ; j < lvl2array.length ; j++)
{
var seek = body.findText(lvl2array[j]);
if( seek != null)
{
body.replaceText(lvl2array[j] , "1.1."+lvl2count+" "+fill2array[j]+"\n");
var seek2 = body.findText("1."+lvl2count+" "+fill2array[j]);
seek2.getElement().getParent().getChild().setAttributes(plain3style);
lvl2count++;
}}}
```

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand the current issue and your goal. Can I ask you about the detail of them?

Comment: I'll try to explain it differently:

Comment: I want to replace the placeholder {{HEADER1.1}} with a text "1.1 Energy". And I want to make it a heading at the same time. But when I use .setAttributes() on the parent it keeps changing all the document, that follows to be a heading

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `I want to replace the placeholder {{HEADER1.1}} with a text "1.1 Energy".`, when I saw your showing script, `{{HEADER1.1}}` is not used. How about this? And, I thought that in your script, you might want to use more placeholders. So, I cannot still understand your question. I apologize for this. Can I ask you about the detail of it?

Comment: So the `{{header1.1}}` wasn't in the array that looks for all the replacements, that's right. I forgot that, when I edited the Code for the question, so it wouldn't be unnecessarily long. I edited this now. Thank you. Regarding the placeholders: The Document, which has all the placeholders in it, is longer. Also, the array in the script that has the placeholders in it is longer, as well as the one that has the replacement texts .

Comment: Thank you for replying. In your current script, the text is replaced by `body.replaceText(lvl2array[j], "1.1." + lvl2count + " " + fill2array[j] + "\n");`. And, although I think that `seek2.getElement().getParent().getChild().setAttributes(plain3style)` occurs an error, it seems that you are trying to find `var seek2 = body.findText("1."+lvl2count+" "+fill2array[j])` and set `DocumentApp.ParagraphHeading.HEADING3`. Unfortunately, I cannot imagine your goal. I apologize for this. Can you provide the sample input and output situations as the images?

Comment: I deeply apologize that I try to correctly understand your question.

Comment: From `I want to replace the placeholder {{HEADER1.1}} with a text "1.1 Energy". And I want to make it a heading at the same time.`, I thought that you might want to replace and reflect "HEADING3" to `{{HEADER1.1}}`. But, in your actual goal, you might want to use these placeholders of `[ "{{header1.1}}" , "{{header1.2}}" ]`? I apologize for my poor English skill.